# How do I repeat text with a php loop based on a $variable?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, echo

I want to repeat `echo("text!")` as often as `$variable` in PHP.

So, let's say:

```php
$variable = 3;
```

Now I want the output to be:

```
text! text! text!
```

How do I code this as a loop? I've tried the following but the loop isn't stopping as it should:

```php
$variable=readline(1,10)
for ($variable>0; $variable<11; $++){
echo("text!"); }
```

Comment: A FOR loop comes instantly to mind as it did to you ! Otherwise WHY would you have added the `for-loop` Tag

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking for a bit of help with your homework. Beginners are welcome, but we expect a good faith attempt at an answer from you first. 
Although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: $variable=readline(1,10)
for ($variable>0; $variable<11; $++){
    echo("text!");
}

I don't know if the for-loop is the way to do it. I'm new at coding and just doing this foruniversity. sorry if I appear stupid to you lol

Comment: Reason: `$++` just does not increase the $variable value and so will never end the looping, you should use `$variable++` . On the other hand, `$variable>0;` should be `$variable=0;` because the 1st parameter is to set the initial value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use loop or str_repeat:

```php
$variable = 3;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $variable; $i++) {
    echo 'text! ';
}
```

*or*

```php
echo str_repeat('text! ', $variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways: use a function

(e.g. echotest($var1, $var2) which use a for loop to do the job)

```
<?php
$variable=3;
$string="text ! ";

echotest($string, $variable);

function echotest($var1, $var2){
 for ($i=0; $i<$var2; $i++) { echo $var1; }
}
?>
```

You may simply change $variable (say change to 3000) and $string (say change to "Covid-19 ended !! " and see the changed result.

See this sandbox link :

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testso10oct2022b.php